# batch compiling SCSS files into CSS via windows command line

Tags: css, sass, compilation

I am wondering, how to batch compile SCSS files via windows command line...in the older version the command 'sass --watch scssFolder:CSSFolder' will do the job but it seems obsolete in the newest version of the SASS.

Answer (score 2):

The methods you used for the `sass` node module are deprecated in the latest version, so you have two (and more) options:

**Option 1: using node-sass**

This is the option with less effort. You already have Node.js installed (and npm), so you can install the [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) compiler running `npm install -g node-sass`. After all the install is complete, you will be able to watch or compile an entire folder (or a single file).

`node-sass input.scss output.css` will compile a single file.

`node-sass input/folder -o output/folder` will compile a entire folder.

With the `-w` option you can watch a folder:

`node-sass -w input/folder -o output/folder` will watch a folder and compile the files to theoutput folder.

Just run `node-sass --help` for a complete list of options.

**Option 2: using Ruby SASS**

You need to install [Ruby](https://rubyinstaller.org/) and the install the [Sass Gem](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) by running the following command line `gem install sass`. After all the install is complete, you will be able to `watch` or `update` (compile) an entire folder (or a single file).

`update` will compile a single file or multiple files in a folder (depending on the parameters). `watch` will do the same and after the initial compilation is completed it will watch the file or all the files in the specified folder, so everytime a change is detected on any of the target files, `sass` will compile the changed ones.

Both options have the same command line sintax:

```
sass --watch input/folder:output/folder
sass --watch input.scss:output.css
```

So, to compile all the files in a folder:

```
sass --update path/to/input/folder:path/to/output/folder
```

And to compile and then watch a folder:

```
sass --watch path/to/input/folder:path/to/output/folder
```

Just run `sass --help` for a complete list of options.

Hope it helps!

Comment: TNX @muecas for your reply.but as far as i understood, there is no command for batch compiling a folder in the newest version of the SASS or at least i haven't found yet.if there is plz let me know.

Comment: @ahmad I installed the latest version just to test this, and it worked. Ruby 2.5.1 and Gem Sass 3.5.6.

Comment: So let’s make things clear: if I want to do batch compiling, I do have to install Ruby on my machine anyway, otherwise it’s not possible to do batch compile a folder ... Am I right?!

Comment: You can’t even run sass without ruby! At least the version with the options you mentioned. You could run others versions, a version for node ja for example. Which version are you running?

Comment: I have used bower to install SASS...
the SASS version i'm using is (1.3.0 compiled with dart2js 2.0.0-dev.50.0).
nothing extra is installed on my machine and i'm just able to batch compile single files via windows command line...

Comment: Can you run `npm -g ls —depth=0` and tell me the exact name of the sass compiler and version?

Comment: C:\Users\AHMAD\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- bower@1.8.4
`-- sass@1.3.0

Comment: Its not a large dash before depth, it’s two short dashes.

Comment: You have a few options then. I will update my answer so you can choose the best for you.

Comment: TNX @muecas for your answer and for your dedicated time...God bless you :-)

Answer (score 0):

sass watch is not implemented for the moment in the darts version, to compile your .scss files you can use

```
sass filename.scss filename.css
```

If you want you can still use the ruby version but it will be obsolete soon.

Comment: TNX for the reply.but as far as i know, the command you mentioned is just able to compile a single file and i am intent to compile the whole content of the scss folder of the bootstrap.

Comment: @ahmad oh sorry! Do you have try to replace the filename by the folder name ?

Comment: That won’t work. The proposed sintax is for single file compilation only.

Comment: @muecas ok, so ahmad you have to use the ruby version if you want to use  sass --watch

Comment: There is no other `sass` command for window, just the one from the Ruby Gem.

Comment: Now that Sass Ruby is obsolete, is it still not possible to batch compile .scss files using dart-sass?